# Import a class from a jython script to another and vice versa

Tags: python-import, jython, importerror, jython-2.7

I am working with two jython programs in which there are two classes inside. One must be imported into a program and vice versa.
This would be the first program:

```
from program2 import myPane 

# executing myPane
myPane()

class classToExtend:
   # [...]
```

The other program is almost identical:

```
from program1 import classToExtend

class newClass(classToExtend):
   [...]
```

In both cases I have the same error `ImportError: cannot import name myPane` or `ImportError: cannot import name classToExtend`. 
Probably a cyclical entanglement is going on that ends up not making things work. I'd like to know how to import only these features and keep the code clean.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mzjn Done, I fixed the title. It all seems okay now. I was thinking of making a drawing...

Comment: I'm running it... However, I corrected it if it is not clear to you. "Help God help you" says the proverb...! @mzjn

Comment: Don't worry, I'll explain it to you. In script 1 I import class `x` from script 2. In script 2 I import class `y` from script 1. Everything ok so far? Well, let's move on. When does the error occur? The error occurs if In script 2 I import class `y` from script 1. That's all @mzjn.